# Mobile Safari browser not getting closed in iPad Air 2 (iOS 8.1) on executing webdriver.quit() command (Using Appium iOS)

Tags: java, ios, selenium, mobile-safari, appium

**Issue Description:**
On executing the selenium scripts, after running both Appium server (UI Version) and ios_webkit_debug_proxy, the Safari browser is getting launched successfully in iPad Air 2, it does all testing as given in script, but once the script execution is done, when the webdriver.quit() command is executed to close the browser, it is not closing the browser.

When the next script is executed, it is opening one more new tab in the existing browser. In short, when it is executing the fourth script, there would be four tabs in the browser.

**Version Details:**

1. **Mac:** Yosemite OS X 10.10.2
2. **XCode:** 6.4
3. **iOS:** 8.1
4. **Appium:** 1.4.8
5. **Appium Java Client:** 3.1
6. **Selenium Standalone jar:** 2.47.0
7. **Browser used:** Safari
8. **Device Used:** iPad Air 2

Please let me know if you any more detail is required.

Any help is highly appreciated.